# ClickOnce Application Won't Open

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm having an issue where if I open the .appref-ms file - it will open the ClickOnce dialog box... Then close. The application won't load - just the ClickOnce popup.

However, if I navigate into Local > Apps > 2.0 ... To the actual .exe file - this opens just fine.

Worth also noting that it is only bugging out like this on *some* devices. I.e. on my machine, opening the .appref-ms file opens the ClickOnce dialog, does the update (if applicable) and then opens the app just fine. Yet one of our customers called to raise the issue.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the application.
I've tried clearing out the stuff in Apps > 2.0 ...

Not really sure how else I can debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some trace in event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the new update to Windows Defender.

I've had to disable Windows Defender for the time being until there's a patch to this problem.

Other people have already figured out the link between the update and ClickOnce apps.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/954ad3f0-a718-4443-86fd-49877abd130f/after-a-clickonce-application-update-application-wont-start