# Why can't I select "update after install" in clickonce WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, .net-5

I have published my .net 5.0 WPF application to a UNC network directory. From there I ran "setup.exe" to install the appliation on my computer. Then when I ran the application it showed the "verifying application requirements" dialog which then disappeared without launching the application.

Running the application directly from the exe from the UNC path works fine. I have investigated this and it looks like it might be a case of this issue here:
[ClickOnce Application Won't Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639621/clickonce-application-wont-open)

Which points to a solution of selecting thee "after the application starts" option in the "Application Updates" window. **The problem is I can't select this.** Clicking the radio button "After the application starts" shown in the image below does nothing:

[image]

Why can't I select this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "After the application starts" option is no longer supported in after .NET Core 3.0:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-update-strategy?view=vs-2019

> For .NET 3.1 and newer applications, checking updates before the application starts is the only update option supported.

This doesn't help me resolve the issue of why my clickonce application won't start but at least I know why this option is unavailable.